# Testing Void in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: testing

I have single project(c#) and have the following codes.
Everything is working fine. But I just want to know
how to test it and view the result in Visual Studio 2010.
I am classic asp developer and always use `Response.end()` to get result. but no idea how to do it in c# project. Thanks.

```
public static string ApplicationLocationList()
{    
    GetApplicationLocationListTableAdapter getApplicationLocationListTableAdapter = new GetApplicationLocationListTableAdapter();

    DataTable dtgetApplicationLocationListTableAdapter.GetApplicationLocationListData(Library.MovieClass.saveApplicationID);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string cityList = dt.Rows[i]["City"].ToString();
                string stateList = dt.Rows[i]["State"].ToString();
                sb.Append(cityList + "," + stateList + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your reference to the `Response` object, I'm guessing this is an ASP.NET project. If you want to see the contents of `sb` on the page, you could try the following:

```
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
Response.Flush();
```

That should write the contents of the `StringBuilder` to the `Response` buffer & the `Flush()` method should send it down to the client page.

If you want to see only the empty `string` returned, you could just omit the `Write()` method & just `Flush()` the response, which should show you only a blank page after the postback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is an ASP.NET application, in which case you want to use `System.Web.HttpApplication.CompleteRequest` as an equivalent to `Response.End`, and `Response.Write(sb.ToString());` before the `return sb.ToString();`.

If it's a console application, then use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());` in the same place.